# How can I close an active dropdown menu when I click on another dropdown menu button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I want to close the already open dropdown menu when one clicks on another menu button that opens its specific dropdown menu.

I found how to do it with vanilla JS, but not with jQuery.

```
<li>
    <div class="menu-list-container">
        <a href="#">Dropdown Menu 1</a>
        <div class="dropdownmenu1-button">
           <img src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu1">
        <li><a href="#">li 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="menu-list-container">
        <a href="#">Dropdown Menu 2</a>
        <div class="dropdownmenu2-button">
           <img src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu2">
        <li><a href="#">li 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="menu-list-container">
        <a href="#">Dropdown Menu 3</a>
        <div class="dropdownmenu3-button">
           <img src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu3">
        <li><a href="#">li 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<script>
    $('.dropdownmenu1-button').click(function() {
       $('.dropdown-menu1').toggle();
    });
    $('.dropdownmenu2-button').click(function() {
       $('.dropdown-menu2').toggle();
    });    
    $('.dropdownmenu3-button').click(function() {
       $('.dropdown-menu3').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

I need to find a way to close `dropdown-menu1`, `dropdown-menu2`, and `dropdown-menu3` when clicking on any dropdown menu button using jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to add for each ul a class like drop-menu like the example below, after you click all the ul will close and open the target one.

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu1 drop-menu"></ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu2 drop-menu"></ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu3 drop-menu"></ul>
<script>
    $('.dropdownmenu1-button').click(function() {
       $('.drop-menu').toggle();
       $('.dropdown-menu1').toggle();
    });
    $('.dropdownmenu2-button').click(function() {
        $('.drop-menu').toggle();
        $('.dropdown-menu2').toggle();
    });    
    $('.dropdownmenu3-button').click(function() {
        $('.drop-menu').toggle();
        $('.dropdown-menu3').toggle();
    });
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>
    <div class="menu-list-container">
        <a href="#">Dropdown Menu 1</a>
        <div class="dropdownmenu1-button">
           <img src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu1 dropdownShareClasName">
        <li><a href="#">li 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="menu-list-container">
        <a href="#">Dropdown Menu 2</a>
        <div class="dropdownmenu2-button">
           <img src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu2 dropdownShareClasName">
        <li><a href="#">li 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="menu-list-container">
        <a href="#">Dropdown Menu 3</a>
        <div class="dropdownmenu3-button">
           <img src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu3 dropdownShareClasName">
        <li><a href="#">li 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">li 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<script>
    $('.dropdownShareClasName').click(function() {
       $('.dropdownShareClasName').slideUp(); // close dropdown function
       $(this).slideDown(); // open dropdown function
    });
</script>
```